# DeMoivre's approximation to the ratio of $\binom{n}{n/2}$ to $2^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics, math-history

I'm reading Stigler's History of Statistics and am trying to understand as many of the derivations as I can.  Stigler begins his discussion of DeMoivre's contributions by stating the result that the ratio of the maximum term of $(1+1)^n$ - that is, $\binom{n}{n/2}$ - to the sum of all terms, $2^n$, when $n$ is large is approximated by

$$
2\frac{21}{125} \cdot \frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}{\sqrt{n-1}}
$$

The constant, $A=2\frac{21}{125}=2.168$, Stigler says, was found by numerical evaluation of the first four terms of the series

$$
\ln\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{12}-\frac{1}{360}+\frac{1}{1260}-\frac{1}{1680}+\dots
$$

As an aside, the constant $A$ was later shown by Stirling to be $\frac{2e}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$.

I'd like to understand DeMoivre's derivation of this result in detail, but so far my attempts to reproduce it have failed. I am, evidently, not DeMoivre's equal.  Could someone please show me the way?

EDIT:

I was able to find [this link](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath642/kmath642.htm) which explains one possible line of argument.  I am disturbed by the leap that leads to equation 1, but perhaps this was the norm in the 1700's?

Comment: Fixed a typo.  Thanks @ThomasAndrews.

Comment: So, by the comments, that means that DeMoivre (your spelling of his name is inconsistent) did not have Stirling's approximation available?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That is correct.  Stigler writes: "Indeed, it is clear from DeMoivre's account that he had a practical equivalent to "Stirling's formula" before Stirling turned to this problem..."